# Swift: How to unzip file not contained in my bundle?

Tags: swift, macos

I am not very familiar with Swift programming but I need to write a small tool in Swift which can unzip a file (and then launch a program). I need to unzip a file which is not contained in my app bundle. It is located in /Users/me/folder1/folder2/openjdk-11.0.2.zip

I tried the libraries "Zip", "ZipFoundation", and "SSZipArchive". From what I read so far, I think that the libraries which I tried need the zip file to be located in the app bundle but I am not sure.

With "Zip" I tried:

`_ = try Zip.quickUnzipFile(URL(string: openjdkZipUrl!.relativePath)!)`

With "ZipFoundation" I tried:

```
let fileManager = FileManager()
let archive = openjdkZipUrl
let destinationURL = openjdkFolderUrl
do {
  try fileManager.unzipItem(at: archive.url, to: destinationURL)
} catch {

}
```

ZipFoundation told me "Value of type 'FileManager' has no member 'unzipItem'" but I imported it with `import Foundation`. I also have it (and the other libraries) in my Podfile.

With "SSZipArchive" I tried:

```
let success = SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: openjdkZipUrl!.path, toDestination: openjdkFolderUrl!.path)
```

The used paths are

```
let openjdkZip = "file:///Users/" + user + "/folder1/folder2/openjdk-11.0.2.zip"
let openjdkZipUrl = URL(string: openjdkZip)
```

and

```
let openjdkFolder = "file:///Users/" + user + "/folder1/folder2/openjdk-11.0.2"
let openjdkFolderUrl = URL(string: openjdkFolder)
```

Is it really a problem that the zip file is not contained in my bundle? Can someone tell me what I did wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm presuming that this on a MacOS project as you are accessing the users folder. Firstly you shouldn't need the zip file to be in the bundle. You might not have permissions to access the folders, check those, use FileManager to check the file exists too before you try to unzip. do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Indeed - if this is a Mac app then sandboxing will be in operation and checking the file permissions won't help as additional checks are in place to prevent the app from accessing otherwise accessible files.  OP: Please update your question with details of sandboxing etc.

Comment: Yes, it is a Mac app. I am sorry for not mentioning this.

@Scriptable I checked whether the file exists beforehand:
```if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: openjdkZipUrl!.path)) {
... try to unzip ...
}```

And the program jumps into this if branch.

Comment: I don't get error messages but Zip told me that the operation could not be completed. I looked into the code but could not find a case which would definitely apply to my implementation. SSZipArchive told me nothing but the return value of the unzipping method was `false`. This means that it was not successful. I could not try ZipFoundation because it told me that FileManager does not have a member called 'unzipItem'.

Comment: I don't do MacOS development, only iOS. As patricia suggested, your app is sandboxes and unable to access files on the filesystem

Comment: @trojanfoe I am sorry, I don't understand your comment and don't know what you want me to do :(

Comment: @PatriciaSauer Mac apps are sandboxed by default which means they have no access to a user's files unless they ask for it by getting the user to open the file/folder.  You should ensure it's turned off for your app, however you are testing if the file exists and if this is succeeding then it looks like sandboxing is not turned on?

Comment: I don't know how to check this. But because the conditional branch is entered, I guess that I have access.

Comment: Thank you so much @trojanfoe for your hint! I googled for it and now found it under the .entitlements file. "App Sandbox" was set to "yes". I set it to "no" and now it is working! :)

Comment: @PatriciaSauer No problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@trojanfoe mentioned in the comments:

> Mac apps are sandboxed by default which means they have no access to a user's files unless they ask for it by getting the user to open the file/folder. You should ensure it's turned off for your app, however you are testing if the file exists and if this is succeeding then it looks like sandboxing is not turned on?

I looked at the .entitlements file in my project and found out that "App Sandbox" was set to "YES". I set it to "NO" and it worked perfectly.

It seems that you can check for a file while in sandbox mode (as I did with my condition) but not access them when trying to unzip them.

Thanks again @trojanfoe :)